# 700MB/s Write on SSHD? FreeNAS and $20 SATA Controler

Tags: hard-drive, sata, speed, freenas, hybrid-storage

Host:
Proliant Ml350 G5 
2X Xeon Quad-Cores @ 2.55Ghz
32Gb DDR2 ECC
Storage Controller cheap $20 4 SATA port PCIe controller SERBIA I think
Disk Seagate Iron Wolf 1TB SSHD 
Freenas 11.1

Ran a DD speed test output below but from my math thats 753.25MB/s Write!?! and 1546MB/s Read !?!

So not trusting that on a seperate server (dl360 G5) over cat 7 and gigabit switch I got 993 MB/s read!

Is this Correct?

> Write

```
[max@nasnode1 /mnt/VM]$ /usr/bin/time -h dd if=/dev/zero of=sometestfile bs=1024M count=10
    10+0 records in
    10+0 records out
    10737418240 bytes transferred in 13.594422 secs (789840016 bytes/sec)
            13.67s real             0.00s user              13.65s sys
```

> Read

```
[max@nasnode1 /mnt/VM]$ /usr/bin/time -h dd if=sometestfile of=/dev/null bs=1024M count=10
    10+0 records in
    10+0 records out
    10737418240 bytes transferred in 6.623533 secs (1621101331 bytes/sec)
            6.68s real              0.00s user              6.67s sys
```

> seperate server read speed

```
max@HYPNOS:/media/NAS$  dd if=sometestfile of=/dev/null bs=1024M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 1.08145 s, 993 MB/s
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Am I getting an accurate reading 700MB/s seems high not to mention full gig read?

Comment: I guess that buffering is confusing your results. After writing the file, and given your 32GB RAM, the whole 10GB file could be in memory and it is this that you are accessing on your read tests. Also, write buffering means that the command could  complete before the data are written to the physical disc.